# Dynamic buttons don't open modal in jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables, modal-dialog

I have a tabbed panel, each pane has a Datatables list with buttons to edit or remove each single row in tables.
Below the image of the first panel as soon as the page is loaded
[image: working first tabbed pane]

Below on of the other panel selected
[image: Other panel not working]

Each edit actions button should open a modal form to edit the row data in Datatables, but they don't work.
I mean, just the Edit actions button in the first Bases pane work fine...the buttons in the other tabbed pane don't open the modal.
Just the Add grey button in each pane can open the modal...and I think that it's due to the fact that the gray "Add" buttons are static...not dinamically created by AJAX call like the rows in the Datatables.

I'm getting crazy to figure out how this weird issue can be fixed.

Below the HTML code to create the page ( just a piece of HTML for each tabbed pane ):

```
<!-- Register pane content -->
<div class="tab-pane" id="register-tab">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-sm table-bordered mb-0" id="register-table">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Registration</th>
                            <th>CofR</th>
                            <th>From</th>
                            <th>To</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <button type="button" id="add-registration-button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light mt-2">Add Registration</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code to load the Datatable is the following:

```
//Ajax datatables
var registerTable = $('#register-table').DataTable({ 
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    searchDelay: 500,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    stateSave: true,
    paging: false,
    ordering: false,
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    ajax: {
        url: controller_url + '/get_aircraft_registrations/' + aid,
        type: "GET",
    },
    columns:  [
        { data: "registration" },
        { data: "cor" },
        { data: "registerDate" },
        { data: "cancDate" },
        { data: "action", responsivePriority: -1 },
    ], 
    createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
        $( row ).find('td:eq(3)').attr('data-id', data.id);
    },
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: -1,
            title: 'Actions',
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false,
            render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                return `
                <td>
                    <div class="button-list">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info waves-effect waves-light"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil edit-registration"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger waves-effect waves-light"><i class="mdi mdi-close remove-registration"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </td>`;
            },
        },
        {
            targets: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false,
        },
    ],
});
```

The most important piece of jQuery code, I think, is the following one, to open the modal when each button is clicked

```
$("body").on("click",".button-list .actions",function(e){
    var $btn = $(this);
    
    var id = $btn.closest('td').data('id');
    
    if(id != null) {
        e.preventDefault();
       
        if($btn.hasClass("edit-base")) {
            console.log('you want to edit base with id ' + id);
            editBase(id);
        }
       
        if($btn.hasClass("remove-base")) {
            console.log('you want to remove base with id ' + id);
            deleteBase(id);
        }
    }
});

function editBase(id){
    console.log(`Editing base with id ${id}`);
   
    $('#baseModal').modal('show');
}
```

Thanks a lot for nay help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) on your datatable initialization.

```
"initComplete":function( settings, json){
    $("body").on("click",".button-list .actions",function(e){
       var $btn = $(this);
    
       var id = $btn.closest('td').data('id');
    
       if(id != null) {
          e.preventDefault();
       
          if($btn.hasClass("edit-base")) {
            console.log('you want to edit base with id ' + id);
          }
       
          if($btn.hasClass("remove-base")) {
            console.log('you want to remove base with id ' + id);
          }
       }
    });
 }
```

You can put your button click functionality inside the initComplete so that after rendering all the data in the datatable it will initialize next the button.

Comment: Thanks a lot for invaluable help. Issue fixed